# pointer to a vector element crashes

Tags: c++, c, linux, stl, segmentation-fault

```
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    int * p = &v[0];
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);    
    }
    *p = 5;
```

I know vector reallocated new piece of memory to increase capacity, but p is just a pointer to some memory address and p itself didn't change. Also memory pointed to by p is in the address space of the same process even after the vector reallocates. Why would it crash?

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer value after the memory has been freed results in undefined behavior.Maybe it crashes, maybe it makes you breakfast in bed. It depends on what day you were born I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change your code to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    int * p = &v[0];

    printf( "Old: %08X\n", &v[0] );
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);    
    }
    printf( "New: %08X\n", &v[0] );

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

You will see that the memory address of `&v[0]` is almost always different to what it was before the reallocation. That means the pointer you created is now pointing to (potentially) invalid memory.
You now just have a pointer `p` pointing to some block of memory. There are no guarantees as to what is in that block of memory, or even if it is valid.

Comment: wont the address pointed to by p still be in the same process address space? why would it be an invalid address?

Comment: @Medicine Yes, but being in the address space doesn't make memory valid, it just makes it accessible. To be valid memory needs to be currently allocated by the program.